# How can I perform statistical analysis, (PCA sPLS-DA) etc on a dataset which has many missing values?

Tags: pca, descriptive-statistics, missing-data

I have a dataset of mass spec analysis which was sent to me in 200 excel files. Importing into R, I get a dataframe that looks like this:

| Unique Sample ID | Chemical Name | Concentration |

| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |

| 001| Chemical 1| 50|

| 001 | Chemical 2| 100|

| 002 | Chemical 1| 100|

| 002| Chemical 2| 50|

| 002 | Chemical 3| 100|

Sample 1 is missing any entry for chemical 3. Can I analyze this data by PCA, as there are no NA values, or what can I do to improve this dataset for statistical analysis? I'm really lost. Thanks!

*edit - Values not included are below the limit of detection so were not exported from the MS to the excel files

Comment: Hard to answer without more detail, but [tag:multiple-imputation] is a common solution to missing data problems.

Comment: To try multiple imputation, would every sample have to have a row in the df for every chemical? Currently some samples have ~20 chemicals, while others have ~200 detected. The method was an unknowns screen, so it only pulled what it found, rather than looking for anything specific.

Comment: I reiterate: please include more details about the data in your question.

Comment: If they're missing because they're below the detection limit, sample them from a uniform distn between 0 and the detection limit? Presumably the minimum observed value for each chemical is a reasonable estimate for the detection limit if you can't get it from the manual. Or just fill with 0s?

Comment: That's really helpful thanks! How statistically "acceptable" is it to fill the data with zeros? Will it skew my results?

Comment: Practically it probably wouldn't affect the results very much (depending on how large the detection limits are relative to the typical scale of data that *was* observed). It could mess with log transformations which are fairly common with this kind of thing. I'd favour sampling from uniform distns and replicating the full analysis a few times while doing so, but you'll probably find that filling with zeros leads to very similar results. Another option would be to fill with the midpoint between 0 and the detection limit. Try them and see how robust the analysis is to those choices, I'd say.